# How to convert a dict to tensors in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix

I am following the tutorial about tensorflow: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

There are lots of categorical features which have to be converted to sparse matrix with `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`.

BUT, I do not want to use the predefined Estimator,

```
m = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir, feature_columns=base_columns + crossed_columns)
```

I prefer to use a costumed NN model, with:

```
estimator = tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=model)
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn(df, num_epochs=100, shuffle=True), \ 
              steps=100)
```

So in `model()`, there will be

```
 def model(features, labels, mode): 
    ...
    node = tf.add(tf.matmul(features, w), b)
    ...
```

Then, I got the errors like:

```
 TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor.
 Contents: {'education': <tf.Tensor
 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:1' shape=(?,) dtype=string>, 'age':
 <tf.Tensor 'random_shuffle_queue_DequeueUpTo:2' shape=(?,) dtype=float64> ...
```

My question is how to convert the `features` to a tensor that can be used as input.

Hope I have described the question clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

features is a dict of `Tensor` you can get a `Tensor` by like `features['education']`, but this `Tensor` still type of `string`, it still can't use `tf.add(tf.matmul(features, w), b)`, you should process your string type feature into numberical feature with like `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`.

## Update:

You can check offical [dnn implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py) , in `def dnn_logit_fn` part, it use [`feature_column_lib.input_layer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column_lib.py) to generate input layer from `features` and `columns`,  and the `columns` is a list of `tf.feature_columns.*`.

When defining a `tf.feature_columns.*` such as `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list()`, it accept string which must exists in `features.keys()` as first parameter, it connects a tensor from `features` to a feature_column to tell tf how to process the raw input (string) tensor into a feature tensor(numberical).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But how can I link the converted `features` with the `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator`?